# HP printer not detected on network

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I am running an HP Envy 5530 printer/scanner and have installed HPLIP and also tried to set one up through CUPS (on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04).

I found https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/step4/cups/net which seemed helpful but when I run the command the following occurs:

```
hp-makeuri 192.168.1.72

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Device URI Creation Utility ver. 5.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: Device not found
```

I know the IP is correct (I can see it on the Printer) and my own IP is 192.168.1.69 so why would the device not be found?

Comment: can you ping it? `user@192.168.1.69$ ping 192.168.1.72`

Comment: Sorry - should have said `Destination Host Unreachable`

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to restart my router, laptop and reconnect the printer to the wireless. I was then able to ping it and set it up through the CUPS interface.